# How to disable a submitButton in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

How to disable a submitButton after the data is submitted in Yii2? Thanks.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <?= Html::submitButton('Summit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'test-button']) ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `beforeSubmit` event in js

```
$(document).on('beforeSubmit', 'form', function(event) {
    $(this).find('[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the  `id`  of the submit button then you can add in some javascript to listen to onclick button.

```
$('#submit_button_selector').on('click',function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled",true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is using an id and a onclick event eg:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <?= Html::submitButton('Summit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'test-button', 
      'id' => 'my_button', 'onclick' => '$("#my_button").attr("disabled", "disabled");' ]) ?>
 </div>
```

try

```
'id' => 'my_button', 'onclick' => '$("#my_button").attr("disabled", "disabled"); return;'
```

or

```
'id' => 'my_button', 'onclick' => '$("#my_button").attr("disabled",true); return;'
```

Comment: I have this error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ']' Thanks

Comment: And the js function is the following ? thanks $('#submit_button_selector').on('click',function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled",true);
});

Comment: you can do as  you prefer  .. my answer is for suggest the use  of an id and an onlcik event  .. you can assign  onclikc even as you prefer using a jquery listner of direcltly  in html option ..

Comment: Using Yii2, this does disable the button but nothing is submitted. If I remove the onclick, the submit is sent. Why?

Comment: @MartinPineault  A disabled element is unusable and un-clickable.

Comment: @scaisedge OK, but how do we submit and then disable the button so the user won't push it twice?

Comment: @MartinPineault  . answer  updated  with a suggestion .. let me know

Comment: @scaisedge Nope: Here what I found, first we need to test if form is valid, then disable and use submitForm Yii::JS. Else don't disable button.

Comment: 'onclick' => '$("#formID").yiiActiveForm("validate"); if (!$("#formID").find(".has-error").length) { $("#buttonID").attr("disabled", "true"); $("#formID").yiiActiveForm("submitForm"); }'

Comment: then instead of redefine the onclick event  ..  you should redefine commit using a .submit()  function and inside this function provide check the validation and the disabling..